# ¿Significan lo mismo "morfema" y "desinencia"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado, morfología

Los términos **Morfema** y **Desinencia** parecieran usarse de forma intercambiable en numerosas fuentes informativas. ¿Significan lo mismo o hay alguna diferencia sutil que yo no he identificado? ¿Es alguna de las dos "más" correcta?

Entiendo que a veces ciertos términos tienen un uso histórico y que han cambiado con el tiempo. Si ese fuera el caso aquí, ¿cuál de estos es el que concuerda con la RAE en la actualidad?

Comment: La desinencia es un tipo de morfema, pero hay otras morfemas (que, depende del tipo de análisis, puede o no incluir los lexemas).  La desinencia es un morfema pospuesto, especialmente para los verbos.  Un morfema antepuesto no se analizaría como desinencia.

Comment: Es correcto decir que un lexema añadido a un morfema constituyen desinencia.

Answer (score 3):

Tal y como [comenta guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18733/significan-lo-mismo-morfema-y-desinencia#comment27670_18733), *desinencia* es un subconjunto de *morfema*:

> [**desinencia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=D6QAVPV)
>   Der. del lat. desĭnens, -entis, part. act. de desinĕre 'acabar, finalizar'.
>   1. f. Gram. **Morfema** flexivo pospuesto a la raíz, especialmente la de un verbo.
>
> [**morfema**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Polt8j2)
>   Del gr. μορφή morphḗ 'forma' y -ma.
>   1. m. Gram. Unidad mínima aislable en el análisis morfológico. La palabra mujeres contiene dos morfemas: mujer y -es.
>   2. m. Gram. Por oposición a lexema, morfema gramatical; p. ej., de, no, yo, el, -ar, -s, -ero.
>   3. m. Gram. Unidad mínima de significado. La terminación verbal -mos contiene dos morfemas: persona, primera, y número, plural.

Tal y como comentan en [Definición de morfema - Qué es, Significado y Concepto](http://definicion.de/morfema/)

> Morfema es, en el campo de la lingüística, la unidad mínima analizable que posee significado gramatical. Por ejemplo: yo, no, le.
>
> El morfema, por lo tanto, es un monema dependiente capaz de expresar significado. Cuando se encuentra unido a un lexema (monema no-dependiente), el morfema es la referencia.

Ejemplos de morfemas:

- yo
- no
- le

Ejemplos de desinencias:

- cant**ábamos**

Nótese por cierto que en [Raíz y desinencias](http://palabralia-elverbo.blogspot.com.es/p/raiz-y-desinencias.html) mencionan esta supuesta relación de sinónimos:

> Las desinencias también llamadas morfemas, son las terminaciones que se añaden al lexema o raíz para construir las distintas fomas verbales.

No sé lo suficiente al respecto para poder aportar más contenido a la discusión. Editadme si queréis para aportar datos.

Comment: En tu ejémplo "cantábamos", **cant-** también es un morfema.

Comment: @Rodgrigo sí y no. Depende del sistema de análisis. *cant-* es lexema, y en algunos sistemas, en lexema es morfema, en otros, los lexemas y morfemas se contrastan

Answer (score 1):

Según tengo entendido, las desinencias se diferencian de los morfemas en que estas pueden estar formadas por varios morfemas verbales, dándose únicamente en los verbos:

*cant-áb-a-mos*

---

- **cant**: raíz
- **áb**: morfema de tiempo y modo (pretérito imperfecto de indicativo)
- **a**: morfema de persona (1ª persona)
- **mos**: morfema de número (plural)

Comment: ¿Cómo puede ser -a- un morfema de primera persona, si todas las formas de ese tiempo (_cantaba, cantabas, cantabais_) tienen esa -a-?

Comment: Tiene razón @Charlie, en todo caso sería `cant-á-ba-mos`: *Lexema + vocal temática + morfema tiempo-modo + morfema número-persona*